# Move or copy patches between figures

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

How can I move (or copy) patches between figures in `matplotlib`?

I'm working with a set of pickled figures, and would like to combine them to one plot.
This is no problem when working with line plots, as I can access the data through `ax.get_lines`.

However, when working with histograms, `ax.get_lines` returns `<a list of 0 Line2D objects>`. As far as I can see, the only way to access the plotted data is through `ax.patches`.
If I try to set a patch from one figure to another with `ax.add_patch`, I get `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`.

### Edit

I'm using `matplotlib2.0.0`.
The following example illustrates the problem

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import copy

# Creating the two figures
x = np.random.rand(20)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
nr = 0
for color, ax in zip(("red", "blue"), (ax1, ax2)):
    x = np.random.rand(20) + nr
    ax.hist(x, color=color)
    nr += 0.5

# Copying from ax1 to ax2
for patch in ax1.patches:
    patch_cpy = copy.copy(patch)
    # del patch # Uncommenting seems this makes no difference
    ax2.add_patch(patch_cpy)
# RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

I would like to copy the red patches to the figure with the blue patches.
[image: Red patches to be copied to the figure with blue patches]
[image: Figure where the red patches should be copied to]

### Edit 2

Although @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer worked for the case above, it did not work in the real-life problem I had.
I ended up making a new axis, and manually created new patches like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib import patches

# Creating the two figures
x = np.random.rand(20)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
nr = 0
for color, ax in zip(("red", "blue"), (ax1, ax2)):
    x = np.random.rand(20) + nr
    ax.hist(x, color=color)
    nr += 0.5

# Create another axis
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()

# Copy the properties of the patches to the new axis
for p in ax1.patches:
    ax3.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(p.get_xy(),\
                                    p.get_width(),\
                                    p.get_height(),\
                                    color = "red"))

for p in ax2.patches:
    ax3.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(p.get_xy(),\
                                    p.get_width(),\
                                    p.get_height(),\
                                    color = "blue"))

ax3.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'd need to delete it from the first figure before adding to the second?

Comment: I tried to delete it with `del` before adding it to the second figure, but I still got `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`. Maybe it is possible to remove in another way?

Comment: Maybe it would help to provide a [MCVE] which includes the pickling. This way you can make sure people are talking about the same thing here.

Comment: Good idea :). I added an example. The pickling part of the problem is just meant to explain why I choose to extract the data from the figures, and is excluded from the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the old solution of just deleting the artist doesn't work any more in matplotlib 2.0.
The `patch_cpy` will still be connected to the same axis as the original. You can see this by `print patch_cpy.axes == ax1` which prints `True`.

So the solution can be to just set the `axes` and `figure` attribute of `patch_cpy` to `None`. I have to admit that I'm not sure if this hasn't got any side effects, but, at least the example below works.
Additionally, the copied patch wil still have the data transform of the old axes incorporated. This needs to be updated using `patch_cpy.set_transform(ax2.transData)`.

Finally, to make sure the plot limits cover both the old and newly copied artists, use `ax2.autoscale()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import copy

# Creating the two figures
x = np.random.rand(20)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

nr = 0
for color, ax in zip(("red", "blue"), (ax1, ax2)):
    x = np.random.rand(20) + nr
    ax.hist(x, color=color)
    nr += 0.5

# Copying from ax1 to ax2
for patch in ax1.patches:
    patch_cpy = copy.copy(patch)
    # cut the umbilical cord the hard way
    patch_cpy.axes = None
    patch_cpy.figure = None
    patch_cpy.set_transform(ax2.transData)
    ax2.add_patch(patch_cpy)

ax2.autoscale()    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
In your example I don't get the `RuntimeError` as mentioned in the question. However, it seems like the patches are tied to the figure coordinates? This can be seen if you add for example `10` to the secondly produced `x`

Comment: I think the copied patches still obey to the axes transforms of the old figure . You can observe a funny effect when panning the initial figure (in the first window) and then activate the second (new) window: The red shapes suddenly move by the amount panned in the first window. There may be a way to also set the new axes transforms to the copied artists. I may have a look at that later on. In the meantime, what exactly do you mean by *'adding 10 to the second x'* ? Can you give the command, such that we are talking about the same thing again.

Comment: Hmm...that is some eerie side effects indeed.
One could "add `10` to the secondly produced `x`" by replacing the first for loop with:
`nr =0;
for color, ax in zip(("red", "blue"), (ax1, ax2)):;
x = np.random.rand(20)+nr;
ax.hist(x, color=color);
nr +=10;
`
Great if you would have the time to have a look at it :D, and thank you for your help :).

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the datatransformation which has to be updated in order for the copied patches to actually "live" in that axes.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of each `patch`. Here is an example where all the pathces are copied from one axes to another:

```
import copy

x = np.random.rand(20)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for color in ("red", "blue"):
    x = np.random.rand(20)
    ax.hist(x, color=color)

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
for patch in ax.patches:
    patch_cpy = copy.copy(patch)
    ax2.add_patch(patch_cpy)
```

If you want to remove the patches from the first `axes` you can use `del` to do that, for example deleting every other patch:

```
del ax.patches[::2]
```

Remember to redraw the figure afterward with:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). However, it seems like your example doesn't work. I still get the `RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure`, also if I try to `del patch` after copying the object.

Comment: Ok, maybe it is because we have different versions of Matplotlib.

Comment: Could be. I am using `2.0.0`.